# Hidden field to store the int representation of an enumerated value

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, enums, bind

I'm a total asp.net newbie just fixing a bug in some code.

I want a hidden field that displays the integer representation of a enum.

Currently the following line displays the "Text" / human readable version of the enum.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblNoteType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NoteType") %>'></asp:Label>
```

What do I need to do to the "Bind("NoteType")" so that it displays the int representation instead of the verbal?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just do:

```
<%# ((int)(Eval("NoteType"))).ToString() %>
```

You should be able to cast it directly to an int from the Eval with no need to cast to your enumeration as an intermediate.

I would also suggest not using a label as it includes funcitonality for formatting which is obviously not needed.  You could just use a `Literal` instead and it will maintain all the ViewState for the postbacks you require with none of the Label's formatting overhead.